# Document contenct should display in Multiple line more that 25 line in view in Lotus notes

Tags: lotus-domino

I have a view where I need to display the content of the 25 fields in 25 lines based on id (for example emp id).which is categorized in the first column But the maximum limit of displaying line is 9 in the view. Is there any way I can display 25 fields in 25 lines.

Any suggestion will be appreciable
Rupesh.

Answer (score 0):

Not as a single, multiline entry, no, but you can use "Show multiple values as separate entries" on the column sort tab. You may need to add a preceding column with a unique value like @Text(@DocumentUniqueID) -- it can be hidden, but must be sorted -- if you need to keep individual document values "bundled".